# jquery datepicker shows up without theme

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, google-cdn

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TextBox1").datepicker();

    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image: JQuery Datepicker without css]

Should I be linking any other css files? Or is it a problem with Google CDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `<script>` for `css` instead of `<link>`

EDIT:

and `rel="stylesheet"` is missing

Comment: oops! You are right. But the problem persists even after changing it.

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>

Comment: `rel="stylesheet"` missing also

Answer (score 1):

Still cant figure out how to do it with external CSS. A faster solution was to keep the CSS files local.

Comment: That was a lazy, easy thing to do. Manji, you rock!